Jetpack compose - Update autofilled password on resetting the account password
I implemented Autofill in my application for login screen with AutofillType for password using Jetpack compose. When I reset my password with AutofillType.NewPassword, Google password manager prompt will come and I updated the password. When I agin login into the App, the password manager is not asked to update the password something like "Would like to update password?". How can I update my changed password to Google password manager on next login?
I tried with Autofill.NewPassword

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
